# 500 internal server error in Laravel 4

Tags: php, git, .htaccess, laravel-4

I am trying to migrate my laravel web app to hosting server, uploaded contents and changed the database configuration.

Then I pointed to my web browser like : www.mywebsite.com it will shows **500 internal server error**

Is there any problem in my htaccess file. ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
   Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

or I am working with BITBUCKET GIT.is there any problem with GIT Usage. ?

Thanks & regards

Comment: did you change permissions on the `storage` folder?

Comment: Try after changing RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] to RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]

Comment: no I dont give any permission to storage.

Comment: you have to add /public path in your url or else write code in htacess to remove public path from site

Comment: I am removed public from URL In starting of development. also make the changing of htaccess and files.

Comment: Ask your provider and check Apache error.log to see why 500 is showing up

Comment: Is there any problem with GIT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my own answer. Make sure your folders have `755` permission. I cleared this issue with permission. This is first thing do any others. You can get successful output.
No Issues with .htaccess and GIT.